# Material UI - Disable multiple row selection in DataGrid

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, datagrid, material-ui

I want to prevent the Material UI `DataGrid` multiple checkbox section. When I select the checkbox section, a particular row should be select and the other rows are remain unselected. I tried the `disableMultipleSelection` option but it would not work.

```
<DataGrid
  rows={cycle}
  columns={columns}
  pageSize={10}
  checkboxSelection
  disableMultipleSelection
  onRowSelected={({ data, isSelected }) => {
    setDisplay(isSelected);
    setCycleId(data.key);
    setCycleImg(data.storageRef);
  }}
/>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a tutorial, how you build this project? Your project looks huge! I am missing some parts unfortunately.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To disable multiple row selection, you have to set `checkboxSelection` props to `false`. `disableMultipleSelection` is only available in [`DataGridPro`](https://mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid-pro), not [`DataGrid`](https://mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid).

```js
<DataGrid
  {...props}
  checkboxSelection={false} // or remove it because it's false by default
/>
```

If you want both selection checkboxes and [single row selection](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/selection/#single-row-selection), you may need to control the selection state yourself and remove all but the latest selection when the selection model changes:

```
const [selectionModel, setSelectionModel] = React.useState<GridRowId[]>([]);

return (
  <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
    <DataGrid
      rows={rows}
      columns={columns}
      pageSize={5}
      checkboxSelection
      selectionModel={selectionModel}
      hideFooterSelectedRowCount
      onSelectionModelChange={(selection) => {
        if (selection.length > 1) {
          const selectionSet = new Set(selectionModel);
          const result = selection.filter((s) => !selectionSet.has(s));

          setSelectionModel(result);
        } else {
          setSelectionModel(selection);
        }
      }}
    />
  </div>
);
```

### Live Demo

**V5**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**V4**

[image: Edit 66828464/material-ui-data-grid]

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable time and for this solution. But I am facing an error when I try to implement this code. The Error is exactly showing on the state declaration time i.e An element access expression should take an argument.ts(1011). Can you give any suggestions for this error?
` const [selectionModel, setSelectionModel] = React.useState<GridRowId[]>([]);`
The error is showing on GridRowId[]
And thank you again for your time and solution.

Comment: The codesandbox is forked from the old Material-UI version. I updated the correct type in my answer @Niku1998

Comment: RowId[] still showing error. Make 'React.useState<RowId[]>([]);' to 'React.useState([])'

Comment: @MrOrhan they changed all the type names in the newer version some time ago. See [this PR](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/pull/1069). Replace `RowId` with `GridRowId` should fix it.