# Multiple row selection on checkbox and single selection on clicking the row in MUI DataGrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, datagrid, material-ui

I'm using [MUI `DataGrid` version 4](https://v4.mui.com/components/data-grid/#data-grid) component.

What I want are:

1. to enable multiple selections from the checkbox in the Data Grid (if the user select multiple rows using the checkbox)
2. to disable multiple selections from the row in the Data Grid (if the user selects multiple rows)
3. to enable single selection from the row in the Data Grid (if the user selects another row after selecting a row).

But what I get are:

1. multiple selections from the checkbox are enabled (**what I want**)
2. multiple selections from the row are enabled (**what I don't want**).

For the row selection, I want a single selection only like this answer [MUI - Disable multiple row selection in DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66828464/material-ui-disable-multiple-row-selection-in-datagrid#66828464) but with the multiple selections from the checkbox is enabled.

Here's my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-data-grid-selection-vq1ny

Here is the [documentation for the selection on the Data Grid](https://v4.mui.com/components/data-grid/selection/#data-grid-selection) component.

Note: it's okay to use [`DataGridPro`](https://v4.mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid-pro/) component.

Please let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: 2. and 3. are the same thing?

Comment: yes, you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the `selectionModel` state and check if the user clicks the cell (not the checkbox). If they click the checkbox, `onCellClick` won't be fired, if they click other cells, `onCellClick` will fire, then based on that info to update the `selectionModel` accordingly:

```
const cellClickRef = React.useRef(null);
const [selectionModel, setSelectionModel] = React.useState([]);

return (
  <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
    <DataGrid
      checkboxSelection
      selectionModel={selectionModel}
      onCellClick={() => (cellClickRef.current = true)}
      onSelectionModelChange={(selection, detail) => {
        if (cellClickRef.current) {
          if (selection.length > 1) {
            const selectionSet = new Set(selectionModel);
            const result = selection.filter((s) => !selectionSet.has(s));

            setSelectionModel(result);
          } else {
            setSelectionModel(selection);
          }
        } else {
          setSelectionModel(selection);
        }
        cellClickRef.current = null;
      }}
      {...data}
    />
  </div>
);
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

### Related answer

- [MUI - Disable multiple row selection in DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66830818/9449426)

Comment: wow great explanation and answer. I even don't think about on `onCellClick` prop. I wonder why do you use `cellClickRef.current = true` instead of `setCellClickRef(cellClickRef.current)`?

Comment: @JabalLogian I'm using `useRef` instead of `useState` to prevent extra re-rendering. Every time you call `setState` the component renders again which in this case is unnecessary. When you click a cell to select a row, `onCellClick` and then `onSelectionModelChange` callbacks are invoked regardless if the component renders or not